# How to sum specific columns based on dates

Tags: python, date, pandas

The two data frames are given below:

df1

```
     Start Date  End Date                   
 0   20110706    20110803                   
 1   20110803    20110907
```

df2

```
     DATE       50      51      52      53      54  
  0  20110706   3.51    2.51    1.51    0.51    0   
  1  20110801   10.98   9.98    8.98    7.98    6.98    
  2  20110808   9.45    8.45    7.45    6.45    5.45    
  3  20110906   0       1       23.2    0       1.2
```

Based off of df1, How can I modify df2 so columns are summed based off the range the dates fall within df1 start date(left inclusive).

Modified df2 dates being left inclusive.(with start date and end date range included in the df)

```
       Start Date  End Date    50      51      52      53      54
  0    20110706    20110803   14.49   12.49   10.49   8.49    6.98
  1    20110803    20110907    9.45    9.45    30.65   6.45    6.65
```

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: So to be clear, you want to do basically an inner join on the `DATE` key in df2 such that it is within the Start/End Date range?

Comment: @Tgsmith61591, Correct, and also summing the values of the dates within the range.

Comment: You've tagged this as `excel` are you wanting an answer specific to excel or pandas?

Comment: @EdChum, I made the correction, I removed the excel tag. Thanks

Comment: @EdChum, reformatted Date strings into YYYYMMDD numbers, thanks for the notification, maybe this will make solving process simplier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since dates are duplicated in `Start Date` and `End Date` it's not clear what do with dates in `df2` which fall exactly on the start or end; is it left-inclusive or right-inclusive. Assuming it's left-inclusive you can do

```
df1['Start Date'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df1['Start Date'])
df1.set_index('Start Date', inplace=True)

df2['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df2.DATE)
df2.set_index('DATE', inplace=True)

sums = df2.groupby(df1.index.asof).sum()
pd.concat([df1, sums], axis=1)
```

Comment: I am assuming left-inclusive thanks for the verification!

Comment: When I do this it results in NaN, or empty values for all the numbers. Maybe it is a conversion issue?

Comment: hmm.. works for me. They key step is the second last. First check that the index on both frames is a datetime index. Then check the output of `map(df1.index.asof, df2.index)`. This is the array indicating the groups (`df1.index.asof` is a function which is applied to the index of `df2`). For each date in `df2.index` the output should be the latest date from `df1.index` before that date.

Comment: for some reason `df2['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df2.DATE)` makes the df2 index of DATE  result to `1970-01-01 00:00:00.0 20110706`

Comment: found the issue! replacing `df2['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df2.DATE)` with   
`df2['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df["DATE"], format="%Y%m%d")`  resolves it! Thanks for your help!

Comment: ahh, this is because the values in `'DATE'` are `ints` rather than strings. When you pass an `ints` to `pd.to_datetime` it treats them as nanoseconds from epoch (unless you specify the unit, e.g. `unit='ms'`. If you were to pass a string such as `'20110706'` you wouldn't need to specify the format.